# Coin Toss Probability Using Bayes Theorem

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

In a box, there are the same number of two kinds of coins: the fair coins (50% chance for head) and the biased coins (70% chance for head). One person randomly selected a coin and tosses it twice. Both tosses are tails. What is the probability that the selected coin is a biased coin?

My calculation:

$$P(\text{Fair Coin}) = 0.50,$$

$$P(\text{Biased Coin}) = 0.50,$$

$$P(\text{TT }|\text{ Fair Coin}) = 0.50,$$

$$P(\text{TT }|\text{ Biased Coin}) = 0.30.$$

$$P(\text{Biased Coin }|\text{ Tails}) = P(\text{Tails }|\text{ Biased Coin})*P(\text{Biased Coin}) / P(\text{Tails }|\text{ Biased Coin})*P(\text{Biased Coin}) + P(\text{Fair Coin})*P(\text{Tails }|\text{ Fair Coin}) $$

$$= (0.3 * 0.5)  /  (0.5 * 0.3) + (0.5 * 0.5) = 0.375. $$

But it does not match with the given answer, where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is the formula you have learnt, and what difficulty are you getting in using that formula ?

Comment: @lulu Just made the edit.

Comment: Yes, I saw that (and deleted my prior comment) Your calculation is a bit hard to read.  Where are you using the fact that you tossed $TT$?

Comment: It looks as if you are solving a different problem.  That is, you are assuming that the coin was only tossed once (and came uo $T$).  That's not what was asked.

Comment: @lulu it still comes the same if I take two tails into consideration... keeping P(TT|F) = 0.25/0.50 and P(TT|B) = 0.09/0.30

Comment: The probability that you get $TT$ is $.5\times .25+.5\times .09$, yes?  Of that, the possibility that you got the biased coin accounts for $.5\times .09$... the $.5's$ cancel so the answer is  $\frac {.09}{.09+.25}\approx .2647$

Comment: To stick closer to the spirit of your calculation, $P(TT\cap B)=.09\times .5$ and $P(B)=.5$ so $P(TT\,|\,B)=.09$.  I don't see why you put a $.5$ in the denominator.

Comment: @lulu gotcha! Thank you. I was missing the concept, just reviewed it.

Comment: Also, sorry everyone for the bad text in the question, it's my first time using stack exchange, I'm not familiar with the keys used for the specific tasks. I'll get the hang of it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F$ = fair coin, $B$ = biased coin

$P(F) = 0.5, P(B) = 0.5$

$P(TT|F) = 0.5^2 = 0.25$

$P(TT|B) = 0.3^2 = 0.09$

$P(B|TT) = \dfrac{P(TT|B)\cdot P(B)}{ P(TT|B)\cdot P(B) + P(TT|F)\cdot P(F)}$

You can compute the value

Also learn to shorten expressions by using symbols, eg $F$ and $B$ instead of writing text

Comment: thank you @true blue anil

Comment: Glad to be of help !